# Why in PHP if you use Mkdir recursive flag do the nest directories not chmod?

Tags: php, chmod, mkdir

I am using mkdir to create normally 2 nested directories for a file structure.  The directories it creates are always set to 0755.  The code I am using however is.

```
 mkdir('path_one/path_two', 0777, true);
```

I have tried then doing

```
 chmod('path_one/path_two', 0777);
```

but that only sets the final directory as 0777.  What would cause mkdir not to function properly?

Comment: To be honest, I think that's how I would expect it to work. Giving the perms to all dirs along the way seems a bit reckless.

Comment: Why would that be reckless?  I did just discover a work around, but it doesn't make much sense to me.  $old = umask(0);
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    umask($old);

Comment: In the first event I expect that your `umask` is set to `755`.

Comment: It's reckless because it would not be expected behavior.  The GNU (unix) mkdir() command also does not recursively set permissions with the --mode option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mkdir is functioning correctly. The intermediate directories created are set based on the current umask. You want something like:

```
umask(0777);
mkdir('path_one/path_two', 0777, true);
```

Comment: This will not work. If the `umask` is `0777` every directory will be created with mode `0-0-0`.

To achieve `0777` you have to set the umask to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

> The mode is also modified by the current umask, which you can change
>   using [umask()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php).

Note that any bits that are **set** in `umask()` are **unset** in the result that's used by `mkdir()`. The default umask is 0022 and the default create mode for mkdir is 0777, which gives a result value of 0755. This applies for all created directories.